# Read text file in numpy array by merging two consecutive columns

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to read a text file of 10Go into a numpy array using `numpy.loadtxt`. My file contains a huge number of 0 and 1 separated by whitespaces. I want to merge two values (columns) in one column as described below in the example. Which delimiter I need to use in this case?

Thank you in advance for your replay.

Example:

From this:

```
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0

1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0

0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

To

```
array [ [01,11,10,00],
  [10,10,11,10],
  [00,00,01,11]
]
```

Comment: When you write `01`,  is that equal to `1`? Or must `01` remain a string?

Comment: The easiest way is probably just load the file into an array `a` and then `10 * a[:, 0::2] + a[:, 1::2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

txtcontent  = np.loadtxt('txtfile.txt')
txtcontent = txtcontent.astype(int)
txtcontent = txtcontent.astype('str')

x1 = [''.join(txtcontent[i]) for i in range(len(txtcontent))]
output = [[x[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(x),2)] for x in x1]
print(output)
[['01', '11', '10', '00'], ['10', '10', '11', '10'], ['00', '00', '01', '11']]
```